# Dynamically created html to fetch an image - I want to display the image retrieved before submitting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am dynamically creating the html that loads an image using js. I want to display the image after I have selected it. I found the functions to do this; however, they are not displaying image in my case. I have tried placing the functions before I call "function displayCamp() {" in the "$(document).ready(function(){" as well.

The selection works and displays the image name.

js:

```
function displayCamp() {

    $('#ajaxGetUserServletResponse1').text('');

    sessionStorage.setItem('ssCamp', 'Pack Holiday');

    var dataToBeSent  = {
            ssYMID : sessionStorage.getItem('ssYMID'),
            ssCamp : sessionStorage.getItem('ssCamp'),
    };

    //Get camp details
    $.ajax({
        url : 'CampView', // Your Servlet mapping or JSP(not suggested)
        data : dataToBeSent, 
        type : 'POST',
        cache: false
    })
    .fail (function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        //alert(jqXHR.responseText);
        if(jqXHR.responseText.includes('No camps')){
                $('#ajaxGetUserServletResponse').text('No camps.');
            }else{
                $('#ajaxGetUserServletResponse').text('Error getting joined data.');
            }
        $("#startDate").focus();
    })
    .done(function(responseJson1a){
        // JSON response to populate the Tabs
        dataType: "json";

//      Event structure is:
//         String eventId, String cdId, String eventType, 
//         String eventDateStart, String eventDateEnd, String eventLocation, String eventDetails,
//         String eventNights, String eventNightsBuilding, String eventNightsCanvas, String eventPicture,
//         String eventKm, String eventKmActual, String eventKmOffset

        //Add Tab headings
        $("#tabHeading").find("li").remove();
        var headingItems = '';
        for(var i = 0; i < responseJson1a.length; i++) {
            var obj = responseJson1a[i];
            // data-toggle="tab" is required.
            headingItems += '<li id="' + i + '"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#' + obj.eventId +'">' + obj.eventLocation + '</a></li>';
        }
        $("#my-tabs ul").append(headingItems);

        //Add Tab contents
        var contents = '';
        for(var i = 0; i < responseJson1a.length; i++) {
            var obj = responseJson1a[i];
            // class="tab-pane" is required.
            contents += '<div class="tab-pane fade" id="' + obj.eventId + '">';

            contents += '<div class="row col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">';

            contents += '<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">';
            contents += '<label class="control-label control-label-left col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4" for="photo">Photograph:</label>';
            contents += '<input class="form-control-file col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8" type="file" id="photo" name="photo" placeholder="Photograph">';
            contents += '<img id="campImage" src="#" alt="Camp image" class="img-thumbnail">';
            contents += '</div>';

            contents += '</div>';

            $("#tabContent").append(contents);
            contents = '';
        }
        // show the first tab.
        $("#my-tabs a:first").tab("show");
    })

    function readURL(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('#campImage').attr('src', e.target.result);
            }

            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }

    $("#photo").change(function(){
        readURL(this);
    });
}
```

Comment: I found the below and it only works on the first tab. How can I get it to work for all tabs? This is an issue extends to bootstrap date only shows the calendar on the first tab and click buttons only work on the first tab.

Answer (score 1):

Place the "function readURL(input) {" after "$("#my-tabs a:first").tab("show");"

js:

```
function displayCamp() {

    $('#ajaxGetUserServletResponse1').text('');

    sessionStorage.setItem('ssCamp', 'Pack Holiday');

    var dataToBeSent  = {
            ssYMID : sessionStorage.getItem('ssYMID'),
            ssCamp : sessionStorage.getItem('ssCamp'),
    };

    //Get camp details
    $.ajax({
        url : 'CampView', // Your Servlet mapping or JSP(not suggested)
        data : dataToBeSent, 
        type : 'POST',
        cache: false
    })
    .fail (function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        //alert(jqXHR.responseText);
        if(jqXHR.responseText.includes('No camps')){
                $('#ajaxGetUserServletResponse').text('No camps.');
            }else{
                $('#ajaxGetUserServletResponse').text('Error getting joined data.');
            }
        $("#startDate").focus();
    })
    .done(function(responseJson1a){
        // JSON response to populate the Tabs
        dataType: "json";

//      Event structure is:
//         String eventId, String cdId, String eventType, 
//         String eventDateStart, String eventDateEnd, String eventLocation, String eventDetails,
//         String eventNights, String eventNightsBuilding, String eventNightsCanvas, String eventPicture,
//         String eventKm, String eventKmActual, String eventKmOffset

        //Add Tab headings
        $("#tabHeading").find("li").remove();
        var headingItems = '';
        for(var i = 0; i < responseJson1a.length; i++) {
            var obj = responseJson1a[i];
            // data-toggle="tab" is required.
            headingItems += '<li id="' + i + '"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#' + obj.eventId +'">' + obj.eventLocation + '</a></li>';
        }
        $("#my-tabs ul").append(headingItems);

        //Add Tab contents
        var contents = '';
        for(var i = 0; i < responseJson1a.length; i++) {
            var obj = responseJson1a[i];
            // class="tab-pane" is required.
            contents += '<div class="tab-pane fade" id="' + obj.eventId + '">';

            contents += '<div class="row col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">';

            contents += '<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">';
            contents += '<label class="control-label control-label-left col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4" for="photo">Photograph:</label>';
            contents += '<input class="form-control-file col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8" type="file" id="photo" name="photo" placeholder="Photograph">';
            contents += '<img id="campImage" src="#" alt="Camp image" class="img-thumbnail">';
            contents += '</div>';

            contents += '</div>';

            $("#tabContent").append(contents);
            contents = '';
        }
        // show the first tab.
        $("#my-tabs a:first").tab("show");

        function readURL(input) {
            if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    $('#campImage').attr('src', e.target.result);
                }

                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
            }
        }

        $("#photo").change(function(){
            readURL(this);
        });
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

These are the changes I made:

```
        //Column 2 to contain the image
        contents += '<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">';
        contents += '<label class="control-label control-label-left col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4" for="'+obj.eventId+'">Photograph:</label>';
        contents += '<input class="form-control-file col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8 photo-input" type="file" id="'+obj.eventId+'" name="photo" placeholder="Photograph">';
        contents += '<img id="campImage'+obj.eventId+'" src="' + obj.eventPicture + '" alt="Camp image" class="img-thumbnail">';
        contents += '</div>';
```

And:

```
    $(document).on('change', '.photo-input', function(){
        alert("this.id: " + this.id);
        readURL(this, this.id);
    });

    function readURL(input, id) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('#campImage'+id).attr('src', e.target.result);
            }

            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }
```